# deleteNode have problems

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

my question is about a exercise in lintcode which requires delet node, but for some reason my simple program won't work.

For example, input (1->2->3->4->null, 3) should output (1->2->4->null), my idea is delete next node and "copy" its value to input THIS node.

```
/**
 * Definition for ListNode.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int val) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */ 
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param node: the node in the list should be deleted
     * @return: nothing
     */
    public void deleteNode(ListNode node) {
        // write your code here
        ListNode pnext;
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.next != null) {
                ListNode tempnode = node.next;
                if (node.next.next != null) {
                    pnext = node.next.next;
                }
                else {
                    pnext = null;
                }

                node.next = null; //delete next node
                node = tempnode; // give next node to THIS node
                node.next = pnext; // link next
            }
        }
        else node = null;
    }
}
```

I am very confused about giving value to node, does `node1 = node2` even work? I know `node.val` can. Can anyone simply guide me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include in your post what actually happens, and you did not include the part where you create your list, so I can only assume what happens is that you do not delete 3, but delete 4? Or does it not delete anything at all?

So you have a method that should delete a Node, and the Node you want to delete is given as a parameter. But as your list is only linked one way you have no way of determining the node before it (which holds the reference to the node you want to delete). Actually the delete method should be as easy as this:

```
public void deleteNextNode(ListNode node) {
    if(node == null || node.next == null) return; //nothing to delete
    if(node.next.next == null){
        node.next = null;
        return;
    } else{
        node.next = node.next.next;
    }
}
```

Although I did not test it. As long as you don't store any other references to your nodes this is sufficient, otherwise you need to call next.null explicitely in the else part.

Edit: My function deletes the Node that follows the Node you pass, but you want a function that deletes the Node you pass it. The problem here is that the previous node stores the reference to the Node that you want to delete, but you have no way of determining that Node with only the reference to the Node you want to delete. So either you use this function and always pass the previous node, or you make a wrapper function and run through the list and always safe the previous Node and call the function with that node:

```
public ListNode deleteNode(ListNode start, ListNode deleteMe)
{
    ListNode prev = start;
    if(start == deleteMe) return start.next;
    while(prev.next != null) {
        if(prev.next == deleteMe)
            deleteNextNode(prev);
        prev = prev.next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Note that I made the function return a ListNode, this is always the first Node of the List (in case you decide to delete the first node).
I hope this helps

Comment: Em.. actually I want to delete 3, so i have to linked previous node with 4, which means i need to delete the 4 but copy the node 4 to node 3, then the node 3 is "deleted", since it become node 4.

Comment: This is not how linked lists work. You don't have to copy anything but just change the reference of node `2` to point to the next of node `3` i.e. node `4` and that's it! As I said in my answer below, you are over complicating the problem. Just try once the below piece of code.

Comment: Easy man..Thanks a lot but its not how it works, I tried your idea and failed.. Maybe you can check this link: http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/delete-node-in-the-middle-of-singly-linked-list/

Comment: As user2004685 already pointed out, you don't have to copy anything. If you want to delete Node3, you simply change the reference of Node2.next to Node4. If you run through the list now, you have Node1, Node2, Node4 (as you changed the reference of Node2.next to Node4!). And that's definitely how it works. If you want to pass the Node that should be deleted as reference you should iterate through the list like in user2004685's solution, you don't need to pass the data though, you can simply iterate until you encounter the node you want to delete:
while(nodeToDelete!=currentNode){...}

Comment: One additional note, this is the way to go because copying the data would kinda defeat the purpose of a linked list. Imagine you change your node elements to complex objects, with multiple data elements, arrays, file pointers etc, then copying them gets more and more complex and will consume more and more time. If you change the pointer of the previous node however, it consumes the same time with the same outcome.

Comment: @Benschi Thanks sooooo much for your instruction and I think it makes sense but really can not work, i just copy paste and run like (1->2->3->4->null, 2) it outputs (1->2->4->null) which should be (1->3->4->null). Thanks for your time really.

Comment: No problem, I edided my answere to explain why this is the case, and also a possible solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating it unnecessarily and it is not that tough. As I see, you are just taking the `ListNode` as the parameter and not the `data` which you want to delete. Also, since you are using `if` and not `while` or `for`, you'll never end up iterating the whole list.

You should modify your function to take both the `node` as well as the `data` and start using a loop to iterate the complete list.

Here is the code snippet:

```
private void deleteNode(ListNode node, int data) {
    while(node != null && node.data != data) {
        node = node.next;
    }

    if(node != null) {
        System.out.println("Deleted Node With Data: " + node.data);
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Em.. actually its not about search but about delete, so assume the target node is input.

Comment: *"actually its not about search but about delete"* I am not sure what you mean here. How would you find the target node? This piece of code will do exactly what you are trying to do here. Just pass the node list i.e. `{1->2->3->4->null}` and data i.e. `3` to this method and it will return you the list i.e. `{1->2->4->null}` after deleting the node `3`. Try it once.

Answer (score 0):

I think by:

```
node = tempNode; // give next node to THIS node.
```

You meant:

```
node.val = tempNode.val; // give next node value to THIS node.
```

That way, the next node's value is copied into the current node.
Next you would want to also do:

```
node.next = tempNode.next;
```

This way, the node effectively becomes the tempNode. I think this was your intention.. ?

Comment: Is node = tempNode; used to copy tempNode everything to node?

Comment: node = tempNode would actually make node 'reference' tempNode instead. It would not change node to tempNode. If this is what you need, you would have to change node.val and node.next to tempNode.val and tempNode.next.